Can I play a voice message to a 3rd party?
Suppose someone left me a voice message on my mobile phone, and I then played their message to a 3rd party.
Was it illegal to play the message I received from them to a 3rd party in the U.K.? Who owns the message?

@MichaelHall Consent to be recorded is not the same as consent to have the recording shared beyond the party you were calling. GDPR and other privacy laws likely address this.

@Barmar, I understand, that's why the content matters...

@MichaelHall I'm not sure it matters legally, but practically it probably does. No law enforcement is going to waste time following up on someone sharing a trivial message like that.
